# Splitting String based on

Tags: javascript, split

I have a simple code line:

```
var myarr = str.split(":");
```

This works if user enters `1:23`

However, it is possible the user can enter one more format: `1.23`

Without doing a manual check for strings, is there something I can add to this `split` function to enter multiple values?

Comment: You can split on regular expressions, though [that has some issues](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split).

Comment: Can you use regex? `str.split(/[:.]/)`

Comment: To avoid the issues mentioned by Pointy you could have 2 arrays (one split on ":" and the other on ".") then take the longest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression

```
String.split(/[:,.]+/)
```

Splits on : or , or .

Comment: @KickingLettuce When in doubt, check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

As is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

the `split` method on strings can be passed a regular expression.  Regular Expressions are described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

This means you can split on anything that you can match with a regular expression.  So for example:

```
var string = 'foo';
var array = string.split(/[:.]/);
```

will split on any character that is either `:` or `.`.